# Relationship cardinality between Room table and Reservation table

Tags: sql-server-2012, rdbms

I have two tables in hotel reservation,I cant define their caridnality constraints.

One **entity** room,second **reservation**

I think it is many to one.As many rooms can have a single reservation.However one room can have only one reservation.Or is the relation many to many?

Answer (score 1):

Since a `reservation` needs to be created with a certain time frame, one room can be linked to several reservations for a different time. So, it's a many to many relation.

Let's say you have the room 1 reserved in January and this same room reserved again in March. Then you'd need three tables, one for rooms, one for reservations and the third for the relation room-reservation.

In the following example, the room 1 has the id **1290** which is repeated in the table of relations between rooms and reservations. Also, the id **2056** for the reservation in March is repeated in that table as it has two rooms.

```
t_rooms
-----------------------------
room_id   | room number | ...
-----------------------------
1290      | 1           | ...
1291      | 2           | ...

t_reservations
---------------------------------------------
reservation_id | reservation time frame | ...
---------------------------------------------
2055           | in January             | ...
2056           | in March               | ...

t_rooms_reservations
------------------------
room_id | reservation_id
------------------------
1290    | 2055
1290    | 2056
1291    | 2056
```

Hope this helps. :)

**Update:**

It'd be good to check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization to fully understand how to keep you database design with no or minimum redundancy.

Comment: alot.:)
but wouldnt it be the other way round.many rooms have one reservation?
My reservation table includes cust_id(customer),room_id ,reservation id ,checkindate,checkoutdate.

Comment: In the example the reservation 2056 has many rooms 1 (1290) and 2 (1291).

Comment: In order to resolve many to many.an associative entity is to be made.did u do the same?
Also i had another table by the name ROOM

Comment: Yes, it's many to many. But you need to get rid of the column room_id in your reservation table. To create a relation many to many you need a third table to match the rows of rooms and reservations.

Comment: check in or check out doesnt help?

Comment: in rooms_reservations,what will be the primary key then?

Comment: The primary key for the table rooms_reservations is the pair (room_id + reservation_id). That table is just a bridge to represent the relation many to many and it just have those two fields which are the key as well. This https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgW43deaex8 is not the best explanation I've seen about the subject, but it may help.

Comment: I have a customer table as well.Where i put cust_id in reservations table as foreign key.When i make C_id,Reservation_id as composite primary key in reservations.I guess than the relation would have to be one to many.

Comment: Yes, for the case of customers <--> reservations it'd be a one to many relation. One customer can have many reservations, but one reservation is only made by a single customer.